# Concatenar elementos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com dificuldades em concatenar os elementos abaixo.

Tenho a variável `valorID` que é usada como id, na div, e estou tentando inseri-la no atributo id e `valorPosicao` para o atributo **left**, do css inline.

Porém, não estou conseguindo inserir a informação.

```
var valorID='meuID';
var valorPosicao=20;
$("body").prepend('<div id='+valorID+'style=position:absolute;left:'+valorPosicao+'px;'+'></div>');
```

Comment: Tem um '+' a mais ali no final

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todo valor de atributo de div, deve vir entre "". No caso de usar js deve ser:

```
...

id="'+valorID+'"

...
```

- Segue abaixo seu código *refatorado*:

```js
var valorID='meuID';
var valorPosicao=20;
$("body").prepend('<div id="'+valorID+'style=position:absolute;left:'+valorPosicao+'px;'+'">teste</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

Comment: O navegador adiciona as aspas automático. Mas eu vou com vc, gosto de fazer certinho. :D

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Answer (score 2):

Você não precisa concatenar na string, pode usar os métodos de manipulação de elemento do jQuery:

```
var valorID = 'meuID';    
var valorPosicao = 20;

var minhaDiv = $('<div>'); //Criando a Div 
minhaDiv.attr('id', valorID); //Adicionando Id
minhaDiv.css('position', 'absolute') //Adicionando Css
    .css('left', valorPosicao);

$("body").prepend(minhaDiv); //Prepend na variavel
```

Answer (score 2):

Use o próprio jQuery. Assim basta:

```
$('<div/>', {id: valorID}).css({'position': 'absolute', 'left': valorPosicao + 'px'}).prependTo('body');
```

Segue exemplo para executar. No console aparece a `div` inserida no DOM.

```js
var valorID='meuID';
var valorPosicao=20;

var div = $('<div/>', {id: valorID}).css(
{
'position': 'absolute', 
'left': valorPosicao + 'px'
}
)
.prependTo('body');

console.log(div[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```